# Sorting row group by report items calculation

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a calculation in my report `reportitems!Textbox42.Value - reportitems!Textbox39.value`

How can I sort a row group by this calculation, report items are not accepted in a sort.

I have tried making a calculated field based on the above expression, but get an error that `FieldValue are denying reportitems`

Comment: You will have to repeat the expressions of the 2 textboxes and calculate their difference in your sort expression.

Comment: @WolfgangKais this makes perfect sense..... however I have a visibility expression on one row group on the report to hide any rows where the difference is greater than 0. This seems to affect the ordering of the remaining rows. It appears the sort is working on the total difference and not the difference on the remaining rows.

Comment: If the expressions contain aggregates that operate on different group levels, you might need to adjust the *Scope* parameter for some of the aggregate functions (that are meant to be applied to a containing group level). Can you update your question and add details on the expressions and the placement of the textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `ReportItems!Test.Value` in a calculated field, thats not possible as well as aggregate functions.

You have to write your calculation in your sorting expression of the tablix. For example:

```
'Expression of Textbox1 in Tablix1
=Fields!Sales.Value - Fields!Income.Value

'Expression of Textbox2 in Tablix1
=Fields!Sales.Value / Fields!Income.Value

'The next two expressions are the same
=ReportItems!Textbox1 * ReportItems!Textbox2  'Label1
=(Fields!Sales.Value - Fields!Income.Value) * (Fields!Sales.Value / Fields!Income.Value)  'Label2
```

Go to your tablix under **Tablix Properties > Sorting > Add > Expression** and write in the expression from **Label2**. This way you can sort after your expression.

If you have some groupings in your tablix you can also go to your tablix under **Row Groups > Group Properties (the drop down) > Sorting > Add > Expression**.